# Почему работает код когда все поля заполнены?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код который выглядит так. Код работает, но есть нюанс.

Почему не выполняется отправка формы когда **не** все поля заполненны.

Подскажите что делать. Ну, и критика приветствуется.

```
(function ($, undefined) {
$(function () {

    var form = $("#myForm");
    $("#send").text("Введите все данные.......");
    form.change(function () {
        var selectTerritory = $('#selectTerritory').val(),
            selectRayons = $('#selectRayons').val(),
            selectRayonsTowns = $('#selectRayonsTowns').val(),
            selectTowns = $('#selectTowns').val(),
            selectSMT = $('#selectSMT').val(),
            inputName = $('#inputName').val(),
            inputMail = $('#inputMail').val(),
            formdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: formdata,
            success: function (data) {

                $('#selectTerritory').val(selectTerritory);

                if (data.towns) {
                    var optionTowns = '';
                    optionTowns = '<br><select id="selectTowns" class="chosen-rtl" name="Towns" title="Выберете город"> <option value="">Выберете город</option>';
                    for (var town in data.towns) {
                        optionTowns += '<option value="' + data.towns[town] + '">' + data.towns[town] + '</option>';
                    }
                    optionTowns += '</select><br>';
                    $("#detaleTowns").html(optionTowns);
                    $('#selectTowns').val(selectTowns);
                }

                if (data.rayons_towns) {
                    var optionRayonsTowns = '';
                    optionRayonsTowns = '<br><select id="selectRayonsTowns" class="chosen-rtl" name="RayonsTowns" title="Выберете район Города"> <option value="">Выберете район Города</option>';
                    for (var rayon in data.rayons_towns) {
                        optionRayonsTowns += '<option value="' + data.rayons_towns[rayon] + '">' + data.rayons_towns[rayon] + '</option>';
                    }
                    optionRayonsTowns += '</select><br>';
                    $("#detaleRayonsTowns").html(optionRayonsTowns);
                    $('#selectRayonsTowns').val(selectRayonsTowns);
                }

                if (data.rayons) {
                    var optionRayons = '';
                    optionRayons = '<br><select id="selectRayons" class="chosen-rtl" name="Rayons" title="Выберете район Области"> <option value="">Выберете район Области</option>';
                    for (var rayon in data.rayons) {
                        optionRayons += '<option value="' + data.rayons[rayon] + '">' + data.rayons[rayon] + '</option>';
                    }
                    optionRayons += '</select><br>';
                    $("#detaleRayons").html(optionRayons);
                    $('#selectRayons').val(selectRayons);
                }

                if (data.smt) {
                    var optionSMT = '';
                    optionSMT = '<br><select id="selectSMT" class="chosen-rtl" name="SMT" title="Выберете ПГТ,Село,Деревню"> <option value="">Выберете ПГТ,Село,Деревню</option>';
                    for (var smt in data.smt) {
                        optionSMT += '<option value="' + data.smt[smt] + '">' + data.smt[smt] + '</option>'
                    }
                    optionSMT += '</select><br>';
                    $("#detaleSMT").html(optionSMT);
                    $('#selectSMT').val(selectSMT);
                }

            }
        })
    });


    $("#send").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#send').text('Зарегестрировать');
    // Вот здесь сераилизуется форма но success не проходит(
        var mydata = $("#myForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add.php",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: mydata,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("<h1>Данные успешно отправлены</h1>").appendTo("#yes");
                $('input, select').val('');

                if (data.newUser) {
                    var newUser = '';
                    newUser += '<h1>Ура новый пользователь</h1>'
                    newUser += '<p>';
                    for (var i = 0 in data.newUser) {
                        newUser += data.newUser[i] + '<br>';
                    }
                    ;
                    newUser += '</p>';
                    $('#yes').html(newUser);
                }

                if (data.oldUser) {
                    var oldUser = '';
                    oldUser += '<h1>Уже есть такой пользователь</h1>'
                    oldUser += '<p>';
                    for (var y = 0 in data.oldUser) {
                        oldUser += data.oldUser[y] + '<br>';
                    }
                    ;
                    oldUser += '</p>';
                    $('#yes').html(oldUser);
                }

            }
        });
    });


});
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: А что возвращает сервер после отправки запроса? Может там ошибка на стороне `add.php`?

Comment: Для большего понимания причины добавьте вывод ошибок после отправки запроса. Как в этом примере (в нижней части) http://jsfiddle.net/Ln580frh/

Comment: @DmitryB. 
Requested JSON parse failed.

Comment: @DmitryB. Да была ошибка на стороне add.php, все порешал так что можете оформить как ответ и я проголосую. И теперь ключевой вопрос как же после ответов всех перезагрузить страницу??

Comment: Добавьте для файла `add.php` вывод всех ошибок. В Chrome откройте `Developer Tools`, вкладка  `Network`, фильтр по `XHR` и попробуйте отправить форму. Далее посмотрите что пришло в `Response`.

Comment: @DmitryB. Уже так сделал, увидел ошибку и исправил))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для большего понимания причины добавьте вывод ошибок после отправки запроса. Как в этом примере (в нижней части):
http://jsfiddle.net/Ln580frh/

Добавьте для файла `add.php` вывод всех ошибок. В Chrome откройте `Developer Tools`, вкладка  `Network`, фильтр по `XHR` и попробуйте отправить форму. Далее посмотрите что пришло в `Response`.